# Finding Files in Linux based on Modification TIme

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to get the files which only have modification time say greater than 5 am in Linux assuming the files are modified/created on the same day.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix usage, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com or [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find file modified in the last day `find / -type f -mtime -1`

or

```
##  (year 2014 April day 05 time 05:00:00)
touch -t 201404040500.00 ~/myfile

## Find all files newer then myfile 
find / -newer ~/myfile
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If you have `GNU find` then you can do:

```
find . -name "*" -type f -newermt "2014-04-04 05:00:00"
```

From `man` page:

> -newerXY reference
>          Compares  the timestamp of the current file with reference.  The
>          reference argument is normally the name of a file  (and  one  of
>          its  timestamps is used for the comparison) but it may also be a
>          string describing an absolute time.  X and  Y  are  placeholders
>          for other letters, and these letters select which time belonging
>          to how reference is used for the comparison.
>
> ```
>    a   The access time of the file reference
>    B   The birth time of the file reference
>    c   The inode status change time of reference
>    m   The modification time of the file reference
>    t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
>
>    Some combinations are invalid; for example, it is invalid for  X
>    to  be t.  Some combinations are not implemented on all systems;
>    for example B is not supported on all systems.  If an invalid or
>    unsupported  combination  of  XY  is  specified,  a  fatal error
>    results.  Time specifications are interpreted as for  the  argu‐
>    ment  to the -d option of GNU date.  If you try to use the birth
>    time of a reference file, and the birth time  cannot  be  deter‐
>    mined,  a  fatal  error  message results.  If you specify a test
>    which refers to the birth time of  files  being  examined,  this
>    test will fail for any files where the birth time is unknown.
> ```

Comment: I tried the same it gave an error saying `find: invalid predicate '-newermt'`. Is this an error or is my find not GNU find.

Comment: @DarkMatter It appears that you don't have the most recent version of `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`. What output do you get when you do `find --version`?

Comment: The version details are : GNU find version 4.2.27

Comment: @DarkMatter `newermt` was added in the version `4.4.2`. See if you can update your version.